# The other 26 elements in module `collections`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to dig deeper and climbing higher in learning Python.

In attempting to learn everything about the `collections` module, I am having problems exploring every corner of it.
In the online documentation and in `help(collections)`, it introduces 9 specialized container datatypes, see
[8.3. collections — Container datatypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```
['Counter', 'OrderedDict', 'defaultdict', 'deque',
 'namedtuple', 'ChainMap', 'UserDict', 'UserList', 'UserString']
```

Compared to that list, there are 26 others not specified in the documentation and with only very limited detail in the `help()` output:

```
x = [ i for i in dir(collections) if not i.startswith('_')]
>>> list(enumerate(x, start=1))
[(1, 'AsyncGenerator'), (2, 'AsyncIterable'), (3, 'AsyncIterator'), (4, 'Awaitable'), (5, 'ByteString'), (6, 'Callable'), 
 (7, 'ChainMap'), (8, 'Collection'), (9, 'Container'), (10, 'Coroutine'), (11, 'Counter'), (12, 'Generator'), (13, 'Hashable'), (14, 'ItemsView'), (15, 'Iterable'), (16, 'Iterator'), 
 (17, 'KeysView'), (18, 'Mapping'), (19, 'MappingView'), (20, 'MutableMapping'), (21, 'MutableSequence'), (22, 'MutableSet'),
 (23, 'OrderedDict'), (24, 'Reversible'), (25, 'Sequence'), (26, 'Set'), (27, 'Sized'), (28, 'UserDict'), 
 (29, 'UserList'), (30, 'UserString'), (31, 'ValuesView'), 
 (32, 'abc'), (33, 'defaultdict'), (34, 'deque'), (35, 'namedtuple')]
```

Is it necessary to invest time to explore the other 26?

Comment: Those are just objects in the `collections` namespace. Just as if you wrote a module, and did something like `import xyz`, then if you looked at `dir(my_module)` it would have `xyz` in it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at the `__all__` exported list of globals of the module. This list is larger than just the documented objects for two reasons. The first is that it includes submodules; in this case [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) is listed here as `abc`.

The second is that there are objects added for backwards compatibility; the extra names come from the `collections.abc` submodule. Once upon a time that module didn't exist and those objects lived in `collections` itself before being moved. Names from that module are imported into `collections` to accommodate code that still imports from the old location.

This is [documented on the page you linked](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

> *Changed in version 3.3*: Moved Collections Abstract Base Classes to the `collections.abc` module. For backwards compatibility, they continue to be visible in this module as well.

So of those 26, one is a submodule of `collections`,
 `collections.abc`, and the remaining 25 objects are explicitly there to support backwards compatibility of names moved to the `collections.abc` module.

If you want to learn about the other objects, then you'll find they are documented in their own location. Use `help(collections.abc)` or the [`collections.abc` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html).

Comment: Hope I can contribute such a high-quality answer to community in no time.